# quantity entry in multiples of 50 for multiple inputs

Tags: jquery, html

I've have tried this code to validate the quantity entered by customers so that they can only enter in multiples of 50...

```
$('form.basket').bind('change',function(evt) {
    if(jQuery('input.qty').val() % 50 != 0) {
        alert('Your number is wrong');
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
}
);
```

This works great if there is only one quantity box on the page. However I am trying to get it to work if there is more than one 'input.qty' - I don't want to do any form submission here - any help is much appreciated

Comment: You need to target the control within the current basket. `$(this)` is your *current* basket withing the bind event. Please show your HTML as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`each` function](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to handle all instances separately...

```
$('form.basket').bind('change',function(evt) {
    jQuery('input.qty').each(function(){
        if(jQuery(this).val() % 50 != 0) {
            alert('Your number is wrong');
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

of course you may need to do something with the alert to indicate which input field has the problem.

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lan7W/)

It is also worth noting that alerts can be pretty annoying when used for validation. You might wish to consider updating the UI to indicate an error instead.

[Here is an example with inline validation](http://jsfiddle.net/Lan7W/1/)

Comment: alerting *once per input* might not be such a pleasant user experience :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: Personally I wouldn't even alert once. I would prefer to update the UI to highlight any validation errors.

Answer (score 4):

if you will not be using IE <9 versions this is more simplier

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="demo_form.asp">
  <input type="number" name="points" step="50">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

the `step` attribute will only allow user to input by mulltiple of it.

Note:The `step` attribute of the `input` tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.

Source : [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_step.asp)

Comment: `"if you will not be using IE >9"`... do you mean "IE <9"?

Comment: it was stated in the notes.

Comment: What notes? What was stated in them?... Do you understand what I am trying to say? You have suggested that your example will only work in IE version 9 and lower. So it won't work in IE 10 and above?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('form.basket').bind('change',function(evt) {
    var flag = true;
    jQuery('input.qty').each(function(){
        if(jQuery(this).val() % 50 != 0) {
           flag = false;
           return false;//if one input is wrong,there is no need to verify others
        }
    })
    if(!flag){
        alert('Some number is wrong');
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
}
);
```